# React Autocomplete set array to textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am implementing auto complete functionality in react with below set of code -

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import TextInput from 'react-autocomplete-input';
import 'react-autocomplete-input/dist/bundle.css';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {SetProductList} from '../Redux/Actions/Actions'

function MainPage() 
{
    const iProductsList=[];
    const [productsList, setProductList] = useState(iProductsList)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://localhost:44301/api/login/GetProductList`)
        .then(res=>{ 
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
          alert(JSON.stringify(res.data));
          setProductList({           
           productsList:res.data
         });
           dispatch(SetProductList(res.data));
           console.log(productsList);
        });
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
           <TextInput trigger="" options={{productsList}} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainPage
```

In this code when I put a custom list , I found it to be working -

```
<TextInput trigger="" options={[some element1,some element2,some element3,some element4]} />
```

But when I assign a state to options , it does not work. I have made sure that  my state contains required set of array elements in it -

[image]

What could be the reason / how shall I modify the code to work autocomplete with -

```
<TextInput trigger="" options={{productsList}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing an object with an array - you must pass a standard array or an array of objects.

```js
<TextInput trigger="" options={productsList} />
```

Answer (score 0):

After Doing - `productsList.productsList` , I got the result working.

```
<TextInput trigger="" options={productsList.productsList} />
```